# Mapping an external http load balancer to a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I've created my first Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud

```
gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west1-c
gcloud config set compute/region europe-west1
gcloud container clusters create ___-cluster --num-nodes 1 --machine-type n1-standard-1
```

Started multiple pods:

```
kubectl run ___-wui --image=eu.gcr.io/____________/___-wui:latest --port=80
kubectl run rabbitmq --image=eu.gcr.io/____________/rabbitmq:latest --port=15672
```

Using `kubectl get pods` I can see that two pods are running

```
NAME             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
___-wui-ihggr    1/1       Running   0          1h
rabbitmq-fzt4q   1/1       Running   0          4m
```

Now I expose these two pods:

```
kubectl expose rc ___-wui --type="LoadBalancer"
kubectl expose rc rabbitmq --type="LoadBalancer"
```

Using `kubectl cluster-info` I can see the dashboard url and I can access both applications from there.

Looking at the Network Load Balancing section, I can see my two apps there each with their own IP addresses.

What I want to do now is map these urls on my domain to these apps, for example both on port 80:

```
http://example.com/rabbitmq -> rabbitmqapp
http://example.com/___-wui -> wui-app
```

How would I go about achieving this? My only experience is with mapping urls to instance groups which I don't see in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this by creating an Ingress http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/. There should already be a l7 controller running in kube-system.

Some common caveats that trip users are:
1. Quota
2. Firewall rules
3. Health checks

These are documented here: https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/gce/BETA_LIMITATIONS.md

You can also turn down the [GCE ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/gce/BETA_LIMITATIONS.md#disabling-glbc) and deploy an [nginx contorller](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx) if you just want to get familiar with the Ingress resource without using your GCE quota.